# How can I get the company's fiscal year for a date?

Tags: sql, oracle

The company uses July 1st of this year to June 30th of following year as fiscal year, which is referenced by the year with January 1st. For example, May 20th, 2014 is in fiscal year 2014 and July 21st, 2014 is in fiscal year 2015. I have to show the `hire_date` as well as fiscal year (only 4 digits for of the year).

```
Hire_date
01-jun-98
16-aug-99
02-feb-09
01-mar-06
01-dec-08
17-mar-99
16-feb-07
```

Comment: SELECT 
CASE
WHEN MONTH(HIRE_DATE)>7 THEN
YEAR(HIRE_DATE)+1
ELSE YEAR(HIRE_DATE)
END AS FISCAL
from X;

Comment: whats wrong with this

SELECT 
CASE
WHEN MONTH(HIRE_DATE)>7 THEN
YEAR(HIRE_DATE)+1
ELSE YEAR(HIRE_DATE)
END AS FISCAL
from X;

Comment: `month()` and `year()` are not Oracle functions. You could use `extract()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiscal year is six months ahead of the calendar year, so You could add six months (to the first day of the month to avoid any odditied or rollover with dates at the end of the month), and see what year that is:

```
select hire_date,
  extract(year from add_months(trunc(hire_date, 'MM'), 6)) as fiscal_year
from t42
order by hire_date;

HIRE_DATE  FISCAL_YEAR
---------  -----------
01-dec-08         2009
01-jun-98         1998
01-mar-06         2006
02-feb-09         2009
16-aug-99         2000
16-feb-07         2007
17-mar-99         1999
```

You could use `extract()` and `case`, similar to what Andrew was hinting at:

```
select hire_date,
  extract(year from hire_date)
    + case when extract(month from hire_date) >= 7 then 1
        else 0 end as fiscal_year
from t42
order by hire_date;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7aeef/6).

Comment: Worked. I was just about to post what i did.

Select Hire_data,
case
when extract(Month from Hire_date)>7 then
extract(year from Hire_date)+1
else extract(year from Hire_date)

Answer (score 0):

Worked. I was just about to post what I did, and this worked too.

```
Select Hire_data,
case
when extract(Month from Hire_date)>=7 then
extract(year from Hire_date)+1
else extract(year from Hire_date)
end as Fiscal
from x;
```